# Is there any circumstance that System.arraycopy throws IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm reading the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) of `System.arraycopy` and found something confused me.

> ... if any of the following is true, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown and the destination is not modified:
>
> - The `srcPos` argument is negative.
> - The `destPos` argument is negative.
> - The `length` argument is negative.
> - `srcPos+length` is greater than `src.length`, the length of the source array.
> - `destPos+length` is greater than `dest.length`, the length of the destination array.

And in the statement of `throws`, it says

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if copying would cause access of data outside array bounds.

I'm wondering...
**Why they use IndexOutOfBoundsException but not ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?**
I tried all the circumstances stated above, and all threw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException actually.
So is there any reason so that they avoid using the subclass of IndexOutOfBoundsException in the JavaDoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to already know, `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is the parent class of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  I think that by returning a more generic type of exception, Java can keep its `System.arraycopy()` API more flexible.  Suppose in the future that another type of index bounds exception is thrown by `System.arraycopy()`.  If the API used the rigid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` then anyone using the method might have to refactor his code.  On the other hand, by using `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, the code remains flexible, and new types of exceptions can be handled with minimal hassle.

So in summary I would say that Java did this out of good design practice.

Comment: Umm... it may be the reason, but I want to argue if it is necessary to use a more generic type in `arraycopy` because it is totally related to operations of arrays. As you know, we shouldn't throw Exception in any circumstance just because it is more generic.

Comment: @choasia This is precisely my point, that in the future the broader exception may be related to multiple exceptions being thrown by `System.arraycopy()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm wondering whether there will be any reason that totally persuades me.

Comment: I think you might be missing the point here.  The concept is no different than coding to an interface rather than to a class.  But in the case of Exceptions, everything is really a subclass, so we can't just use an exception interface, so instead a parent class is being used.

Comment: After reading Javadocs of some other classes, I think your explanation is right. They always use a generic exception in the document. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc:

- `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

  > Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.
- `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

  > Thrown to indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to a string, or to a vector) is out of range.

The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when **any** index is out of range, while `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when an **array** index is out of range.

By throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, they're being clear about what the index is - it is specifically an array index. If they threw an`IndexOutOfBoundsException`, this could refer to any index.

Tl;dr: They're being more specific and clearer.

As to why the documentation says it throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, but actually throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` does extend from `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, so they can be classified under the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and it's easier to simply refer to the superclass, but ultimately throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because it's more precise. You also use `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in try/catch blocks a lot more than `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so this make it easy to catch an exception from `System.arrayCopy()`, but also makes it easier to be more specific when catching the exception.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is more specific?

Comment: @Choasia Yes, in this case, by throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` they're being more specific about what the index is.

Comment: So you agree with me that they should also use ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the JavaDoc to respect consistency?

Comment: @Choasia No, please see the edit to the post for more detail, but it's better to use `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in the javadoc. It's more recognized, and it's easier to refer to the exception by its superclass.

Comment: Yes, I think I figured it out. Thanks for your help.